# could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;) | Laravel 5.8 | SQLite | Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, ubuntu

This error occurred after moving my project from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04.

*The development of the project included:*

- Windows 10
- Laravel 5.8
- php7
- SQLite

The way i transferred the project files was through USB Drive. I need to mention that due to rushing my transition to Ubuntu for work needs i'm not yet comfortable with all the differences compared to Windows. I installed php7.4, sqlite3 and apache, fixed some simple errors after first starting the project and then came upon this error. I read about some similar cases but i'm yet unable to resolve this problem.

***.env** DB configurations*

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

***config/database.php** configurations*

```
//Never had an error before with the 'mysql' value. Chaning it to 'sqlite' didn't fix the problem
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),  

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
            // I tried changing the value true to false. It just changes the error log
        ],
```

Comment: Make sure that the sqlite PHP extension is loaded. You can create a test php file with phpinfo() on it and see if the sqlite extension is loaded or not. If not loaded, you need to enable it in php.ini file

Comment: SOLVED. PHP extension was loaded -checked with phpinfo() - but the sqlite3 driver was not enabled despite me downloading it previously.